# IF and ISBLANK in an array

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm a noob when it comes to advanced Excel. I'm currently using this formula that I found online and altered to my spreadsheet:

```
=IF(ROWS(G$7:G7)>$D$2,"",
    INDEX(Test!G$2:G$999999,
          SMALL(IF((Test!$A$2:$A$999999>=$B$2)*(Test!$A$2:$A$999999<=$B$3),
          ROW(Test!$A$2:$A$999999)-ROW(Test!$A$2)+1),ROWS(G$7:G7))))
```

Essentially I'm pulling information from a different worksheet, corresponding to a specific date range. I've left the cell range as row999999 so that I don't have to update the formula as I enter new data over the months/years.

I'd like to leave cells blank if it is pulling from a blank cell - currently it is coming up as zero's.

I tried putting an IF or ISBLANK in front, but it's makes all the cells (even those with data) to go blank.

Comment: It's the initial clause which should determine whether a blank is returned or not, not the main array formula. As such, can I ask what you have in cell D2?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put an `IF(ISBLANK(...))` around your `INDEX` function. Something like this:

```
=IF(ROWS(G$7:G7)>$D$2,"",
    IF(ISBLANK(INDEX(Test!G$2:G$999999,
                     SMALL(IF((Test!$A$2:$A$999999>=$B$2)*(Test!$A$2:$A$999999<=$B$3),
                     ROW(Test!$A$2:$A$999999)-ROW(Test!$A$2)+1),ROWS(G$7:G7)))),"",
       INDEX(Test!G$2:G$999999,
             SMALL(IF((Test!$A$2:$A$999999>=$B$2)*(Test!$A$2:$A$999999<=$B$3),
             ROW(Test!$A$2:$A$999999)-ROW(Test!$A$2)+1),ROWS(G$7:G7)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Re "*I've left the cell range as row999999 so that I don't have to update the formula as I enter new data over the months/years*" this is, I'm afraid, a terrible idea.

I know you think you're "hedging your bets" by setting such an upper reference, but you're actually doing far more harm than good.

Unlike `COUNTIF`, `SUMIF`, `COUNTIFS` or `SUMIFS`, for example, array formulas calculate over all cells passed to them, whether technically beyond the last-used cells in those ranges or not.

So if, for example, you only have data extending as far as row 1000, then, by referencing 999,999 rows, you are effectively forcing Excel to calculate nearly one million more cells than are actually necessary, resulting in an astonishingly resource-heavy formula. And that's just for one instance of that formula.

With some functions you can get away with referencing entire columns with no detriment to performance, though not with functions which operate over arrays, such as `AGGREGATE`, `SUMPRODUCT`, and any construction requiring `CSE` (`CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`).

As such, you should either choose a suitably low, though sufficient, upper bound for the end row being referenced or, even better, makes your ranges dynamic, such that they automatically adjust as your data expands/contracts.

Regards